# how to get the position of the scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, scrollbar

I want to get the position of the scroll bar (not the **scrolltop** position) but all I see is only $(document).scrollTop(). Can someone help me with this. For my understanding, the $(document).scrollTop() gives the top most visible position of the window, but I want the exact position where user's scroll bar slider is.

[image]

**EDIT:** I have added more explanation. I need to get the position of the scroll bar itself so as I can put some div (as the one with arrow in the image) follow the scroll bar.

Comment: yes `.scrollTop()` gives you that way, what is _exact position_ btw.

Comment: Actually I don't need the dimensions of the topmost visible part of the window, I need how much pixels has the scroll bar has been scrolled from its position. Assume you have to make an application where a div follows the scroll bar's position, how to do this?

Comment: You can read about [**.scroll()**](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) of jquery.

Comment: .scroll() is an event while I need the position of the scrollbar.. how will .scroll help me with that? I need to know what should be the code to be written inside .scroll().

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I thought you need to maintain the arrow button always in the center of the page. If this is your need means, you can apply the fixed position for the arrow div, like below:

```
    .arrow {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
    }
```

So that, the arrow element always maintained in the page center position even the page scrolls.

Comment: no, the scroll will not always be in the centre, it can be a little up, a little down or far away from the center

Comment: There is no need to consider the scroll position. If you apply the style to the arrow element, then it is always maintained in the page center position, ant it does not depends the scroll bar position.

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't explain it to you, I want the arrow position to follow the scroll position.. I want it to be on top of the page, when scroll bar is at the top, when scroll bar is at bottom, the arrow should also be at the bottom.